# Raspberry Pi Zero W as an access point

Tags: wifi

I want to set up my Pi Zero W as an access point running a Mosquitto MQTT server.
The Pi Zero W is fairly new, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to set it up as an access point.

Comment: What makes you think tutorials for RPi 3 wouldn't apply? Both boards use exactly the same WIFI chip.

Answer (score -1):

Try these instructions.  I've had a pi zero w running as an access point using these.
[pi access point](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview)

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.